# Like to store multiple passwords in db table wp_posts field post_password?

Tags: password

I like to have a multiple password access for a page. And i was thinking of just adding 200 passwords in post_password field but that's too simple and post_password is varchar(20). How else can i have multiple passwords?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the code of this plugin [Multiple Passwords for Protected Pages](http://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-multiple-pass-for-protected-pages/)

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @s_ha_dum i just needed a post to be access only by selected passwords. I ended up with a function and a custom db table. I then create shortcode for the function  which checks if the password is valid and shows the content else it doesn't. btw now sexy or save password lookup, just straight away.

Comment: "now sexy or save password lookup" -- What? o_0

Comment: I haven't looked this up, just an idea. Maybe in the admin you can enter several passwords separating them with commas. Then try to change the password query from = to %LIKE%.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i meant to say "i am not using a sexy or secure password processing" trying to be sarcastic/cynical too myself ;)